# Multiplication with identity matrix in Direct2D - why?

Tags: c++, matrix, direct2d

I'm using C++. I saw `[here](-here I should add the link-)` the code below on MSDN:

```
m_pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();
m_pRenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity());
m_pRenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White));
```

I wonder why they multiply with the identity matrix. It makes no change:
`I * A = A` if `A * B = C`. `I * C = C`, not `C * I = A`, so it's not `C * I = A`, but my friend said if I `SetTransform(identity)`, rendertarget becomes initial state.

Why do they multiply with the identity matrix?

Comment: Please show what you tried, what your sources are... Carefully read [ask] before asking your next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684172(v=vs.85).aspx) this syntax is to be used when one wants to ***To remove the current transform***

They say if you have:

```
 pRenderTarget->SetTransform(
    D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation(20, D2D1::Point2F(100,100)));
```

> The transform is applied to all subsequent drawing operations until you call [`SetTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742857(v=vs.85).aspx) again. To remove the current transform, call `SetTransform` with the identity matrix, which is returned by the [`Matrix3x2F::Identity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd372258(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

```
pRenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity());
```

Comment: My understanding was If I want something to be transformed then I should multiply transform matrix and calling settransform makes things transformed so settingtransform is multiply... I know im stupid. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The initial transform maybe be zero or it may be garbage (uninitialized) or it could even be identity but we dont know. So you should set it to identity so that you know what the transform is. Regardless of what the initial transform actually is you should assume that it is unitialized and assign it a value before you use it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the initial transform is identity, otherwise you would always have to set a transform (which most applications probably don't) or otherwise the drawing would get messed up.

Answer (score 0):

`SetTransform` should not be confused with something like `MultiplyTransform` (which doesn't exist). You are *setting* the transform, not appending to it. In Direct2D, it's up to you to do push/pop style matrix manipulation.